# How do I check if an input value is a valid string?

Tags: python

So I'm making a game of hangman and it starts with a "BotMaster" entering a string and then how many guesses that player will have to try and guess the string. I only just started and I'm trying to write a function that will check if what the BotMaster put is a valid string. A valid string would be a string that is only letters, no symbols, numbers, or extra spaces. I already have the functions that will remove extra spaces, and non-alpha inputs (So it takes out periods, extra spaces and such) and a function that makes it all lower case, but my function breaks if I enter a number an empty string. How should I add these?

```
#Imports (this is for later code I haven't written)
import os,time,random

#Removes extra spaces from the function
def space_cull(the_str):
  result = the_str 
  result = result.strip()
  result =" ".join(result.split())
  the_str = result
  return the_str

#Makes the string lowercase
def make_lower(the_str):
  the_str = the_str.lower()
  return the_str

#Checks if everything in the string are Alpha Inputs
def check_alpha(the_str):
  the_str =''.join([char for char in the_str if char.isalnum()])
  return the_str 

#Ask Botmaster the string they want
def ask_bot():
  while True:
   bot_str = input('Enter a string for the player to guess: ')
   bot_str = space_cull(bot_str)
   bot_str = make_lower(bot_str)
   bot_str = check_alpha(bot_str)
   if bot_str == '':
      print('That is not a correct string, try again')
      True
   return bot_str

ask_bot()
```

I added the ask_bot() part so I can test the function faster
This is what happens:

```
Enter a string for the player to guess: 1
#nothing 
#Tested again:
Enter a string for the player to guess: ''
That is not a correct string, try again.
#But then exits the loop, which I don't want it to, if the string is wrong I want it to ask them again.
#Tested Again
Enter a string for the player to guess: 'Katze'
#Nothing, which is actually good this time
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `s.isalpha()` will return True if the string `s` contains only letters, and False otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop will always terminate in the function as it is written.

```
def ask_bot():
  while True:
   bot_str = input('Enter a string for the player to guess: ')
   bot_str = space_cull(bot_str)
   bot_str = make_lower(bot_str)
   bot_str = check_alpha(bot_str)
   if bot_str == '':
      print('That is not a correct string, try again')
      True # <- this does nothing
   return bot_str # < - this breaks out of the function and the loop
```

Your code edited to work:

```
def ask_bot():
  while True:
   bot_str = input('Enter a string for the player to guess: ')
   bot_str = space_cull(bot_str)
   bot_str = make_lower(bot_str)
   bot_str = check_alpha(bot_str)
   if bot_str == '':
      print('That is not a correct string, try again')
   else: # returns the string if the input is correct
      return bot_str # this still breaks out of the function and the loop
                     # but only if the string has passed the checks
```

As other answers already mention, you could use str.isalpha() to check that the string is valid, or if you would like to modify the string in place you will need to adjust your check_alpha function like so:

```
def check_alpha(the_str):
  the_str =''.join([char for char in the_str if char.isalpha()])
  return the_str
```

Comment: but how do I make that if it isn't a correct string it will ask the Bot Master again to enter a correct string?

Comment: the modified ask_bot() function does that - by adding the else statement the function keeps asking for a new string until a correct string is passed.

Answer (score 0):

As John Gordon already mentioned the solution is the method "isalpha" of the "str" class.

```py
userInput = input("Your suggestion: ")
if userInput.isalpha():
    # do some magic
else:
    print("please only type in letters")
```

Comment: I want to use try and except to make the risk of a crash even less, I've written some code but it will continue to the next function even if it isnt alpha.

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need the check_alpha(str) function at all. Modify the ask_bot() as follows.

```
def ask_bot():
  while True:
   bot_str = input('Enter a string for the player to guess: ')
   bot_str = space_cull(bot_str)
   bot_str = make_lower(bot_str)
   if not bot_str.isalpha():
     if bot_str.isnum():
       print("The entered string is a number")
       continue

     if bot_str == '':
       print('That is not a correct string, try again')
       continue

     continue

   break

return bot_str
```

ask_bot()

Comment: It says continue is not in the loop properly

Comment: check the edits, should be fine now. I made a typo while typing the if-block. It was originally meant to be in the loop. Apologies

Comment: That's ok :) I make mistakes all the time. I called the Hilbert Curve the GILBERT Curve lol

Comment: It did! I have one question though, so it catches if i enter just 1 as the input and says its a number and returns it which is good, but if I enter '1' it lets it pass. Is there any wa of catching that?

Comment: Great! Sure, check the edit. Adding an additional 'continue' should do it. Also, do upvote if it works! Thanks